# jQuery Validate: required field is empty but validating true

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Here is what I am seeing in my web console:

```
validationRules.rules.NameOnCard.required //true

document.OForm.NameOnCard.value //""

$("#OForm").validate().element("#NameOnCard") //true
```

The field is required, it is empty, and it is valid. What am I doing wrong?

As a bit of background, I programmatically make payment info not required until the form shows a balance, then I make it required. If I remove that if/then code, it properly validates. But from what I can tell I am correctly telling validator that that field is now required, so an empty field should validate to false, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your required parameter be conditional like this:

```
NameOnCard: {
required: function(element){
      var fooValue = $('#fooVar').val();
      if (isNaN( fooValue )){
          return false; 
      } else {
        if ( fooValue > 0) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
      }
}
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! However, I would like to apply this logic to a bunch of fields. I tried: NameOnCard: {required: true,validIfDeposit:true}, $.validator.addMethod("validIfDeposit", validationValidIfDeposit, "");
function validationValidIfDeposit(value,element){
      if (isNaN( oForm.thisEvent.deposit.depositAmount )){
          return false; 
      } else {
        if ( oForm.thisEvent.deposit.depositAmount > 0) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
        }
      }
}    But, it always validates false. Worst case, I reuse your code for each field. Thoughts?

Comment: You could just move that function(element)... to its own function (say function checkValue()...) and then call the function at each required like... require: checkValue()

Comment: ok... `function validateIfDeposit(){
      if (isNaN( oForm.thisEvent.deposit.depositAmount )){
          return false; 
      } else {
        if ( oForm.thisEvent.deposit.depositAmount > 0) {
           return true;
        } else {
           return false;
      }
  }
}`

`NameOnCard: {required: validateIfDeposit()},` validateIfDeposit() returns true in console, which should mean required:true, yet the form says that field is not invalid when empty. confusing to me

Comment: You still have to make the function(element)... call on your required line:       required: function(element){
      return somefunction();
     }

Comment: wow, that worked, thanks! not sure I understand why `NameOnCard: {required: function(element){ return somefunction();}}` works but `NameOnCard: {required: somefunction()}` doesn't, but I'm thrilled anyway. I'll just remember to always follow that format!

Comment: For this plugin, that is the required syntax for setting a callback function.  PS - if your original question has been satisfied, please don't forget to mark this as your answer (click on checkmark next to answer). Thanks!

Comment: I just posted a very similar question in a separate thread. I would love it if you could check it out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068588/jquery-validate-creditcard2-how-to-only-validate-the-credit-card-if-the-card-is

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check if the form is valid by doing this:

```
if($("#OForm").valid()){
 // valid
}
```